# A question about the degree of an element over a field extension.

Tags: field-theory

Say $K$ is a field extension of field $F$. If element $b$ is algebraic with degree $n$ over $F$, we know that $[F(b):F]=n$. 
Why is it that $[K(b):K]\leq n$?

Comment: For an easy example of this (just to see one), take $K = F(b)$. Then $[K(b) : K] = [K : K] = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the following facts: if $M/L$ is a field extension, then for any $a\in M$, 
$$[L(a):L]=\deg(h)$$
where $h\in L[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L$. The minimal polynomial of $a$ is the monic polynomial of smallest degree having $a$ as a root. Consequently, if $p\in L[x]$ is any other polynomial having $a$ as a root, we must have $h\mid p$.

Let $f\in F[x]$ and $g\in K[x]$ be the minimal polynomials of $b$ over the fields $F$ and $K$, respectively. Because $F\subseteq K$, we have that $f\in K[x]$. Because $f(b)=0$, we must have $g\mid f$, hence
$$[K(b):K]=\deg(g)\leq\deg(f)=[K(b):K].$$

Comment: Oh cool. So the minimal polynomial itself is changed! Thanks a bunch. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @Ayush: Certainly; for example, the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $x^2+1$, but its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ is $x-i$.

Comment: I had a follow-up question, and I was wondering if I could ask it here, or should I repost it as a separate question. 
If $a$ is algebraic over $F$ with degree $m$, and $b$ is algebraic over $F[a]$ with degree $n$, then $[F[a,b]:F]\leq mn$. True. (I think it should be $[F[a,b]:F]=mn$). How does this imply that $a\pm b, ab$ and $\dfrac{a}{b}$ are also algebraic over $F$, and with what degree? I mean- say $f_{0}+f_{1}a+\dots f_{m}a^{m}=0$, and $f'_{0}+f'_{1}b+\dots f_{n}b^{n}=0$ then how does this prove that there's a degree $k$ such that $f''_{0}+f''_{1}(a+b)+\dots f''_{k}(a+b)^{k}=0$?

Comment: Notation: $f_{0},\dots f_{m}\in F$. 

$f'_{0},\dots f'_{m}\in F[a]$.

$f''_{0},\dots f''_{m}\in F$.